# TFTP fails: server error "unknown option"

Tags: tftp

i am trying to get or put with TFTP protocol. I set the TFPT server and everything worked but stopped working lately. I am able to connect to the server but am getting an error "unknown option -?" when inspecting the Syslog. When running Tcpdump i see the message is "19 RRQ filename netascii"
i have looked for a couple of days in the net but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

from RFC 1350

```
      opcode  operation
        1     Read request (RRQ)
        2     Write request (WRQ)
        3     Data (DATA)
        4     Acknowledgment (ACK)
        5     Error (ERROR)

        2 bytes     string    1 byte     string   1 byte
        ------------------------------------------------
       | Opcode |  Filename  |   0  |    Mode    |   0  |
        ------------------------------------------------
```

This is what you have to see in your RRQ or WRQ packet

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem.
try to install the daemon with
sudo apt-get install tftpd-hpa
after that try to resart the daemon with:
sudo systemctl restart isc-dhcp-server.service
look at the status:
sudo systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service